# Creating array with values less than the threshold using Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I want to pick the minimum in the first row and then select values which are less than this minimum as I scan the succeeding rows. The output should look as below.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.4234101 , 0.73587042, 0.81, 0.83202077, 0.73592897],
       [0.45714687, 0.13144797, 0.67110076, 0.70283126, 0.32859529],
       [0.30888356, 0.84115786, 0.24648344, 0.4963486 , 0.42780253],
       [0.10956774, 0.49696239, 0.17086982, 0.34758674, 0.6332388 ],
       [0.69931352, 0.72449178, 0.98831224, 0.20775389, 0.19041985]])

print(a<0.4234101)
```

The desired output is

```
array([0.4234101 , 0.13144797, 0.32859529, 0.30888356, 0.24648344,
       0.10956774, 0.17086982, 0.34758674, 0.20775389, 0.19041985])
```

Comment: 0.4234101 isn't less than 0.4234101, why shall that be in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could index the first row, find its minimum and create a boolean mask to filter `a` with.

```
a[a < a[0].min()]
```

If you want the minimum as part of the final output, then you could concatenate it to the output above:

```
first_row_min = a[0].min()
np.r_[first_row_min, a[a < first_row_min]]
```

Output:

```
array([0.4234101 , 0.13144797, 0.32859529, 0.30888356, 0.24648344,
       0.10956774, 0.17086982, 0.34758674, 0.20775389, 0.19041985])
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is:

1. Get the minimum from row 0:

   ```
   a0min = a[0].min()
   ```
2. Get following rows:

   ```
   a1 = a[1:]
   ```
3. Get the result:

   ```
   result = np.insert(a1[a1 < a0min], 0, a0min)
   ```

   i.e. get the wanted elements from *a1* (following rows)
   and insert the minimum from the initial row at the beginning.

The result is:

```
array([0.4234101 , 0.13144797, 0.32859529, 0.30888356, 0.24648344,
       0.10956774, 0.17086982, 0.34758674, 0.20775389, 0.19041985])
```

You don't need any explicit iteration over the source array, as it is
performed under the hood by *Numpy*.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
print([i  for i in a.reshape(-1,) if i<0.42])
```

or if you want it linked to the first value:

```
print([i  for i in a.reshape(-1,) if i<a.reshape(-1,)[0]])
```

Answer (score -1):

The method you might want is np.nditer()
which iterates over the single elements of an multidimensional array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.4234101 , 0.73587042, 0.81, 0.83202077, 0.73592897],
       [0.45714687, 0.13144797, 0.67110076, 0.70283126, 0.32859529],
       [0.30888356, 0.84115786, 0.24648344, 0.4963486 , 0.42780253],
       [0.10956774, 0.49696239, 0.17086982, 0.34758674, 0.6332388 ],
       [0.69931352, 0.72449178, 0.98831224, 0.20775389, 0.19041985]])

values = []
min = a[0].min()

for element in np.nditer(a[1:]):
    if element < min:
        values.append(element.item(0))
```

Comment: How do I get the desired output as I mention in the post?

Comment: I'm sorry i think i missed on that, you can simply add .item(0) behind the element, in last line, like i edited